# Azure Data Factory Connect to AWS RDS PostgresSQL Via SSH

Tags: postgresql, azure, ssh, amazon-rds, azure-data-factory

In the past I could successfully connect to an AWS RDS PostgresSQL database from Azure Data Factory that has been enabled with a public endpoint.

Recently we have a scenario where an SSH client is created on an bastion host on AWS EC2 Instance which then connects the PostgresSQL database.

So now we need to connect to this PostgresSQL instance from Azure Data Factory via SSH. It seems that the current driver (ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver) in ADF only supports SSL, so is there another way to set up an SSH tunnel in Azure and connect via the tunnel to the SSH client in AWS.

So in short :

AZURE ADF ----> PostgresSQL Linked Service ---> SSH Tunnel ---> AWS EC2 SSH --> AWS RDS PostresSQL

Thanks in Advance ....

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can achieve this at this as  it is not supported . I request you to go [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory) and log this ask , so that the ask reaches to the right team .